# capybara selenium sqlite error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, selenium, capybara

Anyone know how I can get around this sqlite lock error? I tried sleep but it's not helping.

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:         ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::BusyException: database is locked: commit transaction
```

The test

```
  assert_selector(:css, '#visu', visible: :hidden)
  click_button("show/hide")
   sleep(20)
  assert_selector(:css, '#visu')
```

I am using 'selenium-webdriver',   '~> 2.53.4'

Comment: There are a lot of questions here on stackoverflow covering this error message, does none of them solve your issue?

Comment: Yes, I did research a bit prior to asking. It might be something weird related to this specific version of webdriver because I had to downgrade the gem because of another error.

Comment: I find it highly unlikely this is related to your testing, not directly that is. Can you not use Postgres or Mysql for your development/testing?

Comment: Yea I was planning to use postgres for the testing environment but I was hoping to test first in my local dev environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure database_cleaner and disable transactional testing, however the real answer here is to use a proper DB - Postgres or Mysql (You'll still need to configure database_cleaner - https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner for your tests to work properly)

Additionally you should be able to use newer selenium-webdriver, you just also need to install geckodriver if using FF 48+, or specify marionette: false if using FF 47 as documented at the top of the Capybara README

Comment: ok i'll try this and report back ! and as someone new to testing I am impressed but the number of things to add to test a simple toggle link ! (minitest-rails-capybara, selenium, mozilla,  a new db, cleaners, geckodriver if FF48 :) It seems likes rails should integrate a module for js enabled feature tests

Comment: I think I have some sort of version incompatibility when using the latest version of selenium-webdriver, geckodriver and FF 51 as I get a WebDriverError: unable to connect to Mozilla error.

Comment: @Ayrad without version details and the exact error message it's impossible to say, but Capybaras tests work with the latest versions of all of those